# AngularJs element.height() not a function

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a directive that would influence element width/height. Looking through examples I've seen that you can get/set width/height by referencing appropriate function. For example in link function of the directive I try to do:

```
function link(scope, element, attr) {
   var height = element.height();
}
```

However, in my code I get "Error: element.height is not a function".

Am I missing the reference to some angular.js module/library or documentation is not up to date?

Comment: Which documentation are you looking at. In the official doc, height() is not listed as a method of element: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Height is also accessible sans JQuery from `window.innerHeight`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are not including jQuery angular substitutes its own smaller library, jqLite.  jqLite does not have a height() function for DOM elements, so you will either need to write your own or use the full version of jQuery in your project.

The limited jqLite api is [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Comment: Thanks, my bad - I have been using custom directive and overlooked that height is from jquery. Really wanted to exclude jquery from my AngularJS project... but it seems I'll need to use it ;(

Answer (score 36):

Geoff Genz is correct that jqLite has no `height()` method or equivalent, but there is still a way to get the height of the selected element. Try this:

```
var height = element[0].offsetHeight;
```

`element[0]` returns the pure DOM element (without the jqLite wrapper) which has an `offsetHeight` property.

Comment: I had found this answer at many places but it doesn't work for me. Console shows `0` value

Comment: Works for angular 1.4.8

Comment: The attribute is empty.

Comment: depending on your app, it may happen that at the time of checking the height element is not fully rendered or hidden with css, you just need to wrap your function with setTimeout