# Error $window.height is not a function - ngInfiniteScroll with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to load data dynamically with ngInfiniteScroll and I'm having a problem where I'm getting `$window.height is not a function.`

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7j0yqjk/7/), it's not quite working and I'm not sure why, the data doesn't display on the fiddle yet it does on my local machine.

I'm using [ngInfiniteScroll](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll) and I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: $window.height is not a function

windowBottom = $window.height() + $window.scrollTop();
```

Anyone have any idea why this error appears and how to sort it?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your fiddle doesn't work due to a module instantiation error. Regardless, `$window` is a reference to the global `window` object, and it is not a jqLite/jQuery object. You need to wrap it before trying to access jqLite/jQuery methods.

```
var windowEl = angular.element($window);
windowEl.height();
```

Comment: adding jquery seemed to sort it :)

Comment: You are the SAVER!

Comment: jqLite does not have a height() function for DOM elements. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102519/angularjs-element-height-not-a-function)

Answer (score 18):

For me, including jQuery **before** Angular in html did the trick ...