# Custom Angular directive to dynamically change font size?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, dom, font-size

I have some content on my site that doesn't format well because different browsers/screens render the font-size a little differently. To counteract this, I'm attempting to use Angular to get the height of some `<p>` tags, and if they're taller than my layout allows, lower their font size.

The `<p>` tags I'm trying to manipulate are contained in a directive which generates multiple content boxes based on some JSON.

I have created this directive:

```
spaModule.directive ("resizeParagraph", function() {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        while (element.height() > 400) {
            element.css("font-size", (parseInt(element.css("font-size")) -1 + "px"));
        }
    }
});
```

This is the directive which creates those boxes (this works):

```
<div ng-repeat="data in homeCtrl.homeData" class="content-box">
<img class="content-image" ng-src="images/home/{{ data.imageSrc }}"/>
  <div class="sub-content">
    <h1>
      {{ data.heading }}
    </h1>
    <p resize-paragraph class="large-text">
      {{ data.body }}
    </p>
    <a ng-href="#/{{ data.linkUrl }}" class="box-link">
      {{ data.linkValue }}
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm at home creating custom directives with a source URL, but this is my first go at creating a logical attribute-based directive.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What is your error message in the console window?

Comment: There is no console error. I believe the syntax is right, it's just not performing the expected function...or any function for that matter.

Comment: I made a mockup and I had to include jquery for the code to work.

Comment: @TomaszNguyen, I actually have jQuery that I know works for this issue. The problem is getting it to run after Angular creates all of these elements and populates them.

Comment: I didn't mean that you have to write jQuery code. Does Angular succeed in populating and showing all elements?

Comment: Yep. The directive which creates the content work beautifully. I use ngRepeat to create several formatted "boxes" of content. As I described in my question, part of the layout of those boxes relies of the text being a certain height.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just use CSS media queries?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js), before loading angular.js. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22102725/2913356) post, it is written that Angular is using its own library jqLite to substitute for jQuery when the jQuery library is not included. jqLite does not include a `height()` function. To be able to use height(), you have to include the full jQuery library.

Just add `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>` before the line where you include angular.js.

I tested it with the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.large-text {
  font-size: 600px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="angular.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.homeCtrl = {};
    $scope.homeCtrl.homeData = [
      {
        heading: 'Heading',
        body: 'Body',
        linkValue: 'LinkValue'
      }
    ];
});

app.directive("resizeParagraph", function() {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        while (element.height() > 100) {
            element.css("font-size", (parseInt(element.css("font-size")) -1 + "px"));
        }
    }
});

</script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="data in homeCtrl.homeData" class="content-box">
    <img class="content-image" ng-src="images/home/{{ data.imageSrc }}"/>
    <div class="sub-content">
      <h1>
        {{ data.heading }}
      </h1>
      <p resize-paragraph class="large-text">
        {{ data.body }}
      </p>
      <a ng-href="#/{{ data.linkUrl }}" class="box-link">
        {{ data.linkValue }}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

After some testing, I found the reason why it is not working as expected. The function inside the directive is called, before the expression `{{data.body}}` is executed in the template. It means that at the moment the directive is called, the text inside the paragraph is literally `{{data.body}}`. What you want is to postpone the execution of the directive after the expression has been executed. You can do it as follows:

```
app.directive("resizeParagraph", function() {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(name, function () {
          while (element.height() > 50) {
              element.css("font-size", (parseInt(element.css("font-size")) -1 + "px"));
          }
        })
    }
});
```

I can also confirm that element.height() and element.context.offsetHeight return the same value. The height of the element in px. So, it doesn't matter which of the two you'll use.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm. Something strange is going on. I did as you suggested and now I am indeed getting a result. However, the `.height()` function must be returning a different value than I'm anticipating because I'm getting closer to target dimensions using numbers like 36, rather than hundreds of pixels.

Comment: I also don't understand the relation between `element.height()` and the number 100. You could try to replace `element.height()` by `element.context.offsetHeight`. What I see is that changing 100 to 90 will reduce the element height by 320px in my case.

Comment: Is element not the element the attribute is attached to? I'm attempting to shrink the `<p>` tag to 100px by changing the font size, so that it is definite.

Comment: I edited my answer and I believe it should work now.