# How to get window scrolling function to work in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

After searching at Stackoverflow for previous post, most solution those not solve my issue.

Am migrating from jquery to angularjs. I need to convert this three line of codes from jquery to angularjs

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
var position = $(window).scrollTop();
var bottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
```

Here is the working code for **jquery** which alerts position and bottom values

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(window).scroll(function(){

                var position = $(window).scrollTop();
                var bottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

alert(position);
alert(bottom);
                   if( position == bottom ){

                /*
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'fetch_data.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {row:20},
                            success: function(response){
                                $(".post:last").after(response).show().fadeIn("slow");
                            }
                        });
                   */
                }

            });

        });

        </script>
```

Here is my struggle with **angularjs** but cannot get it to work. Can someone help me

```
    <script>
        var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);

        fetch.controller('fetchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$window', function ($scope, $http, $window) {

angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
var position = $(window).scrollTop();
var bottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

alert(position);
alert(bottom);


if( position == bottom ){
          /*
             $scope.getPosts = function(){

                $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'getData.php',
                data: {row:20}
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.posts = response.data;


                });
             }
*/

            }

});

        }]);

        </script>
```

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: here below is the two line of codes that throws ReferenceError: $ is not defined at object. Please can you help me further Sir.
    .var position = $(window).scrollTop();
var bottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

Comment: Looks like a simple typo. `$(window)` should be `$window`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution that works for me is to implement jquery  before calling angular. see this solution links [AngularJs element.height() not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102519/angularjs-element-height-not-a-function/24169800)

Thanks